# MonetDB: jdbc based queries return -1 as affected rows often even though the query was successful

Tags: jdbc, monetdb

e.g, below query:

```
create table t1 ( age int, name varchar(10) )

insert into t1 values(1, 'name'),(2, 'surname')

 copy select * from t1 into 't1.dat' DELIMITERS '|','
','"' null as '';
```

The copy select cmd returns -1 as the affected row count, although it should return 2 as the value. Not sure why this is so. At many other times, I have seen the same query returning correctly the affected row count.

If I run the same query in the Dbeaver tool Iam using, I see this:

```
Updated Rows:   -1
Query:  copy select * from t1 into 't1.dat' DELIMITERS '|','
    ','"' null as ''
Finish time:    Sat Apr 30 16:53:28 IST 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use an absolute path to the export file, e.g.

```
copy select * from t1 into '/home/user/t1.dat' DELIMITERS '|','
','"' null as '';
```

When you see a message like `2 affected rows`, it might actually be due to the result summary of the successfully completed `INSERT INTO` statement. But that doesn't mean the `COPY INTO <file>` statement is successful though.

Comment: No.. I checked with absolute path also. No difference in behaviour. In fact, if I run the same copy cmd against monetdb version July2017-SP4 I am indeed getting the affected row count for copy into cmd. The issue is with latest version of monetdb

Comment: In that case, if you manage to collect stand-alone steps to reproduce this issue, it might be sensible to file a bug report on the official MonetDB's github site: https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues.